# Is it possible to display the yAxis as a percentage without modifying my datasets for a Line chart?

Tags: chart.js

// EDIT: Added my datasets and unfudged the link

I'm trying to build a stacked area chart without converting my datasets to percentages.  The endgame is that there will always be 100% showing on the chart regardless of which datasets are removed (when clicked on the legend).  [here is what I am trying to emulate](https://www.highcharts.com/demo/area-stacked-percent)

I think I might have to build a plugin for this but I'm not sure.  Here are my options:

```
type: 'line',
data: {
    labels: xAxis_label,
    datasets: [{
        label: "Dataset_1",
        borderColor: "yellow",
        backgroundColor: "yellow",
        data: [60, 45, 82, 100, 12, 22, 45, 56]
     }, {
        label: "Dataset_2",
        borderColor: "blue",
        backgroundColor: "blue",
        data: [15, 217, 8, 219, 4, 16, 115, 9]
     },{
        label: "Dataset_3",
        borderColor: "green",
        backgroundColor: "green",
        data: [840, 750, 910, 874, 799, 610, 612, 839]
     }, {
        label: "Dataset_4",
        borderColor: "grey",
        backgroundColor: "grey",
        data: [15, 22, 5, 17, 32, 40, 44, 8]
     }]
},
options: {
    responsive: true,
    title:{
        display:true,
        text:"sugar honey iced tea"
    },
    tooltips: {
        mode: 'index'
    },
        hover: {
            mode: 'index'
        },
        scales: {
            xAxes: [{
                gridLines: {
                    display: false
                },
                scaleLabel: {
                    display: true,
                    labelString: 'Time'
                }
            }],
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: true,
                    min: 0,
                    max: 100,
                    callback: function(value){return value+ "%";}
                 },
                 stacked: true,
                 scaleLabel: {
                     display: true,
                     labelString: 'Percentage'
                 }
             }] 

         }
     }
 };
```

Comment: Isn't that showing the percentages now? or you wanna show it without using the ticks option?

Comment: No, its appending the % sign to the values from the dataset.  For example: dataset_1: [840, 750, 910, 874, 799, 610, 612, 839], dataset_2: [60, 45, 82, 121, 12, 22, 45, 56].  Dataset values that are > 100 will flow out of the chart.  I will update my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You indeed need to build a plugin to achieve something like that.

Here is a plugin I have constructed, that will get the job done ...

```
Chart.plugins.register({
   beforeDraw: function(c) {
      let ticks = c.scales['y-axis-0'].ticks;
      let step = 100 / (ticks.length - 1);
      let tick = 0;
      ticks.forEach((e, i, a) => {
         let index = a.length - 1 - i;
         a[index] = (tick | 0) + '%';
         tick += step;
      });
   }
});
```

**note :**

You would also need to add the following option for y-axis ...

```
afterFit: function(e) {
   e.width = 60
}
```

This is to resize the chart so that, the y-axis ticks fits properly to the view.

**ᴡᴏʀᴋɪɴɢ ᴇxᴀᴍᴘʟᴇ ⧩**

```js
Chart.plugins.register({
   beforeDraw: function(c) {
      let ticks = c.scales['y-axis-0'].ticks;
      let step = 100 / (ticks.length - 1);
      let tick = 0;
      ticks.forEach((e, i, a) => {
         let index = a.length - 1 - i;
         a[index] = (tick | 0) + '%';
         tick += step;
      });
   }
});

var chartData = {
   labels: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H'],
   datasets: [{
      label: "Dataset_1",
      borderColor: "yellow",
      backgroundColor: "yellow",
      data: [60, 45, 82, 100, 12, 22, 45, 56]
   }, {
      label: "Dataset_2",
      borderColor: "blue",
      backgroundColor: "blue",
      data: [15, 217, 8, 219, 4, 16, 115, 9]
   }, {
      label: "Dataset_3",
      borderColor: "green",
      backgroundColor: "green",
      data: [840, 750, 910, 874, 799, 610, 612, 839]
   }, {
      label: "Dataset_4",
      borderColor: "grey",
      backgroundColor: "grey",
      data: [15, 22, 5, 17, 32, 40, 44, 8]
   }]
};

var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var myBarChart = new Chart(canvas, {
   type: "line",
   data: chartData,
   options: {
      responsive: true,
      title: {
         display: true,
         text: "sugar honey iced tea"
      },
      tooltips: {
         mode: 'label'
      },
      scales: {
         xAxes: [{
            gridLines: {
               display: false
            },
            scaleLabel: {
               display: true,
               labelString: 'Time'
            }
         }],
         yAxes: [{
            afterFit: function(e) {
               e.width = 60 //set that suits the best
            },
            stacked: true,
            scaleLabel: {
               display: true,
               labelString: 'Percentage'
            }
         }]
      }
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.5.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: I noticed that the x-values don't add up to 100%.  Would that be a separate plugin?  Could you also explain what you did with the plugin?  I am new to chart.js and would like to know more, thank you

Comment: you mean x-axis values? if so, you can create a new plugin or extend this plugin for that *(but that would be a diff. question)*. There's nothing much to explain. Inside the `beforeDraw` function, its just plain javascript. You can refer [here](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/plugins.html) to learn more about chartjs plugins